# Algolia conditional search

Tags: php, search, algolia

I have in my Algolia engine the next "entity"

```
Professional
objectID: "eyJpZCI6OX0="
...
status: id: 1
```

And I like to make a search just with the ones that have status = 1.
I've tried this:

```
$searchResult = $this->get('algolia.indexer')->rawSearch(Professional, $data, [
            'hitsPerPage' => 10,
            'page' => 1,
             'facetFilters' => 'status:1',
      ]);
```

Seems that im nos using facetFilters correctly,
any help?
Thanks

Comment: Do you have set `status` attribute as attributeForFaceting (https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/search/filtering-faceting/#prerequisite)?

Comment: @JanPetr Yes i have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see you have sub-attribute `id` inside the `status` attribute. So your record looks something like this:

```
{
  "objectID": "eyJpZCI6OX0=",
  ...
  "status": {
    "id": 1
  }
}
```

Correct?

In this case you need to specify the sub-attribute in your `facetFilters` as well. In your case it would look like this:

```
$searchResult = $this->get('algolia.indexer')->rawSearch(Professional, $data, [
    'hitsPerPage' => 10,
    'page' => 1,
    'facetFilters' => 'status.id:1',
]);
```

If you use [Algolia PHP API client](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-client-php), the code would look like this:

```
$client = new \AlgoliaSearch\Client('foo', 'bar');
$index = $client->initIndex('index_name');

$res = $index->search('', ['filters' => 'status.id:1']);
```

You can also replace `facetFilters` parameter by [`filters`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/php/parameters/filters/) parameter, which is more powerful and allows you to specify more complex conditions.